# Docker Error: failed to solve: error from sender: context canceled

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, devops, theia

I am facing this error while trying to build my docker image for my project. What could be the possible reasons? I am doing the build in VS Code terminal. I have attached the image of the error logs.

> ERROR: failed to solve: error from sender: context canceled

## Setup dev environment

```
FROM node:21-bullseye as build
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y git bash maven openjdk-11-jdk

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
```

## Theia build dependencies

```
RUN apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends \
    software-properties-common \
    libxkbfile-dev \
    libsecret-1-dev \
    build-essential libssl-dev
WORKDIR /home/theia
```

this is the relevant part of my dockerfile.

I was expecting a successful build but this error has been nagging

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to replace the image link with the actual build logs?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with PyCharm. Closing it and using terminal to build the image worked for me.